# PaperTrail: info_for_paper_trail in API controller after authentication method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, paper-trail-gem

I have api controller which is inherited from `ActionController::API`
API authentication is performed with some organization key like

```
   api_key = request.headers["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"]
   @organization = Organization.find_by(api_key: api_key)
```

later I need to set `whodunnit & whodunnit_type` with `@organization`
there are multiple type of organizations

**Question:**
How can I make call to paper_trail method `info_for_paper_trail` after authentication

**Currently what's happening**
`info_for_paper_trail` method is being called before authentication and at that time there is no `@organization`

**What I tried:**

1- I tried `before_action` filter in controller after authentication BUT what happens

- `info_for_paper_trail` method is called 2 times one by default (by PaperTrail) other one which I set by `before_action`. In first attempt there is no `@organization` but in second attempt via `before_action` it set `whodunnit & whodunnit_type` but not saved in db entry of version table.
- Secondly called `info_for_paper_trail` method inside authentication method which also set `whodunnit & whodunnit_type`  but it's not being saved in version table entry.

Comment: Where are we finding **@organization** ? in which controller?

Comment: It's API base controller in `authenticate` method

Comment: and info_for_paper_trail in same controller or different?? i am asking this because we use paper trail to store different versions of record let's say users model. so here  we can call info_for_paper_trail in users_controller before action. hence always API base controller's before_action will be called first and then other controllers before_action